# Dynamic TypoScript generation on template based principle

Tags: typo3, typoscript

Is it possible to generate some parts of TypoScript templates in dynamic way ?

For example, I have a TS template with defined placeholders. I would like to fill it with an array of values (defined in dB, or with TS array of constants), to get filled TypoScript template on the output.

Probably an extension already exists, or it's a hidden core functionality ?

UPDATE :

Just small examples, which could illustrate the use of such demand.

Example 1

```
[globalVar=IENV:TYPO3_HOST_ONLY = subdomain1.domain.com]
    config.baseURL = http://subdomain1.domain.com/
    config.googleMapKey = AAABBBCCCDDDEEEFFF
[global]

[globalVar=IENV:TYPO3_HOST_ONLY = subdomain2.domain.com]
    config.baseURL = http://subdomain2.domain.com/
    config.googleMapKey = AAABBBCCCDDDEEEGGG
[global]
```

Example 2

```
10 = COA
10 {
    10 = TEXT
    10 {
        value = jquery.js
        wrap = <script type="text/javascript" src="|"></script>
    }
    20 = TEXT
    20 {
        value = jquery.plugin.js
        wrap = <script type="text/javascript" src="|"></script>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, if i understood what you want to do, but f.e. your second example could be written like this:

```
10 = COA
10 {
    10 = TEXT
    10 {
        value = jquery.js
        wrap = <script type="text/javascript" src="|"></script>
    }
    20 < .10
    20.value = jquery.plugin.js
}
```

And (untested!) you could also define an constant like:

```
ScriptTag (
        10 = TEXT
        10 {
            value = undefined
            wrap = <script type="text/javascript" src="|"></script>
        }
)
```

And use this in your setup:

```
10 = COA
10 {
    {$ScriptTag}
    10.value = jquery.js
    20 < .10
    20.value = jquery.plugin.js
}
```

Comment: Thanks, malholtz, this solution will answer second part of my question. The syntax, as   understand, should be a little different : `ScriptTag = TEXT ... ... 10 < ScriptTag`

Comment: i guess, the syntax should be ok. With ( ) you can use linebreaks. You will need the linebreaks in your TS Setup. Constant substitution is just an replacement before parsing TS Setup! You could define a constant JustO = O in constants and use it in TS Setup like 10 = C{$JustO}A

Comment: Wow. This approach is very interesting for some situations, if it works. Inconvinient : as I understand, we couldn't use constants inside another constants, so once substitution will be made, the constants inside the "pseudofunction" will stay not-parsed.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of such a feature. And it sounds wrong too. 
Can you describe a little more detailed what you want to archive?

You can of course hook into the TS rendering. In TS you have constands and you may use conditions, switch/case statements, etc.
You can also call a user function at any place that has stdWrap.

Comment: I'm already intensively use described functionalities of TypoScript. To explain better : to reduce the volume of code, which repeats with minor differences, I would like to use data arrays, which will be applied to code templates. It's similar principle as traditional "functions" in PHP and JS, or marker mapping in TYPO3.

Comment: I always copy similar code and then just change the different parts, but I guess that is not what you want. By nature, TS is static, because it just creates a PHP array corresponding on OBJECTS which return a string and FUNCTIONS which work on that string before it is passed to the view. This is highly adapted to the nature of SGML languages which use hierarchical tags. I still do not know where you want to be dynamic. Maybe you can give a longer example?

Comment: I've added some mimimalistics examples. Imagine, if You have 100 blocks of code, which repeats in such way.

Comment: For the first example, you would end up with 100 cache entries for each page, so you better have a look on how to solve this differently and for the second one, you already got an answer. Just as I said, if code repeats, I use the copy operator and only touch the changed parts.